# Material Navigation Drawer - Android

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

i need help with a navigation drawer tutorial, the youtube tutorial is this one:
[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59hLHJT-V44)

So.. im very new to android, this isnt my kind of work, but i was asked to create a simple app for a company, i just need help to create a navigation drawer, because i will use a webview inside, the problem is, how can i open a new activity when i choose and option? or how can i have just one webView in activity_main and when i choose an option the webview URL changes.

This is the code in question(Ben´s code)

[ben´s code](https://github.com/bfdeitch/MaterialNavDrawer)

Thank you guys..

---

EDIT:

So with the bens code i can do something like this?

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // if (position == 0)
    // return HEADER_TYPE;
    // return ROW_TYPE;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //do something
        default:
            //do something
    }
    return HEADER_TYPE;
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) ?

Comment: Yes its working already, thank you :D